# Decrypting AES/ECB in Windows Store App

Tags: javascript, windows, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some data I'm receiving through HttpClient.

The data is encrypted using AES/ECB with a single synchronous key and padded using PKCS#5.

Currently i'm trying -

```
function decryptBlob(blob) {
    var Crypto = Windows.Security.Cryptography;
    var key = "M02cnQ52Ji97wvT7";

    var SAP = Crypto.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.openAlgorithm("AES_ECB_PKCS7");
    var bufferedKey = Crypto.CryptographicBuffer.convertStringToBinary(key, Crypto.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)
    var AES = SAP.createSymmetricKey(bufferedKey);
    var data = Crypto.CryptographicBuffer.decodeFromBase64String(blob);

    var iBuffer = Crypto.Core.CryptographicEngine.decrypt(AES, data, null);
}
```

But this gives me the error :

> 0x80090005 - JavaScript runtime error: Bad Data.

In the function call:

```
var data = Crypto.CryptographicBuffer.decodeFromBase64String(blob);
```

Any ideas of what errors i'm making or how i'm going about this wrong?

Comment: Is that your really key? if so thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Haha no it's not, but enjoy the randomness!!

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you supplied us with the input of the base64. Without it, it is tricky to know what's wrong. Maybe it uses URL safe characters, or maybe it is not padded correctly. Spurious characters, wrong line endings, unsupported line lengths....